# Do not allow https version on landing page

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to disallow https version for landing page only & that is 'index.php'. However when I visit the website 'www.example.com', index.php is not called & so .htaccess file doesn't get what it is.
Until now I was using below code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.example.com [L,R=301]
```

If I do this:

```
RewriteRule https://www.example.com http://www.example.com [L,R=301]
```

This doesn't seem to work. Any help?
Also I want to redirect particular landing page only, because for a login & such pages I redirect it to https version.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$
RewriteRule ^$ https://example.com/index.php [L,R=301]
```

Like this you redirect people who only visit your site over `http://example.com` to `http://example.com/index.php`. After that i've just added your already existing `.htaccess code`, which should work properly now because `index.php` is called

Comment: It involves two redirects, is that okay thing?

Comment: @ShanilSoni thats okay because people don't even see the first redirect, they just call your site, its loading and then they use the site.

Comment: @ShanliSoni You don't even need the second part I've just realized. (Makes no sense to me)